# Error in Xcode: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xe8)

Tags: c++, xcode

This is supposed to be a c++ game which works by reading in files. How ever, I am not really sure what is the problem in the code below. When I enter the file name it gives me this error (code is below, problematic line is also shown). If you can't fix it can you at least tell me why this seems to work fine in another computer, but when I try to compile in Xcode it goes wrong?

```
#include "AdvRoom.h"



AdvRoom::AdvRoom()
{

}

bool AdvRoom::readRoom(ifstream &roomFile)
{
    bool success = true;
    char data[64];
    int pointer;

    while ((roomFile.get(data[0])) && data[0] == '\n') {}
    roomFile.unget();
    if (success && !roomFile.eof() && roomFile.good()) {
        roomFile.get(data, 64);
        this->number = atoi(data);
        roomFile.get(data[0]);
    }
    else success = false;

    if (success && !roomFile.eof() && roomFile.good()) {
        roomFile.get(data, 64);
        this->name = data;
        roomFile.get(data[0]);
    }
    else success = false;
    if (success && !roomFile.eof() && roomFile.good()) {
        roomFile.get(data, 64);
        while (data[0] != '-' && success) {
            this->description.push_back(data);
            if (success && !roomFile.eof() && roomFile.good()) {
                roomFile.get(data[0]);
                roomFile.get(data, 64);
            }
            else success = false;
        }
        roomFile.get(data[0]);
    }
    else success = false;

    if (success && !roomFile.eof() && roomFile.good()) {
        // Check for \n
        string direction;
        int destination = 0;
        string key;
        while (roomFile.peek() != '\n' && success) {
            if (success && !roomFile.eof() && roomFile.good()) {
                roomFile.get(data, 64, ' ');
                direction = data;
                while ((roomFile.get(data[0])) && data[0] == ' ') {}
                roomFile.unget();
                int i = 0;
                while ((roomFile.get(data[i])) && data[i] != '\n' && data[i] != ' ') {
                    ++i;
                }
                if (data[i] == ' ') {
                    data[i] = '\0';
                    destination = atoi(data);
                    roomFile.get(data, 64, '\n');
                    key = data;
                    roomFile.get(data[0]);
                }
                else if (data[i] == '\n') {
                    data[i] = '\0';
                    destination = atoi(data);
                    key = "";
                    //roomFile.get(data[0]);
                }
                AdvMotionTableEntry entry(direction, destination, key);
                this->motionTable.push_back(entry);
            }
            else success = false;
        }
    }
    else success = false;

    return success;
}

vector<string> AdvRoom::getDescription()
{
    vector<string> copyDesc = this->description;
    return copyDesc;
}

string AdvRoom::getName()
{
    string copyName = this->name;
    return copyName;
}

void AdvRoom::addObject(AdvObject obj)
{
    // This function should add the obj to the room.
    // It however, should not add the object to the room
    // if the room already contains the object.
    this->objects.push_back(obj);
}

AdvObject AdvRoom::removeObject(string objName)
{
    AdvObject deletedObj;
    // This function should remove the object with objName.
    for (int i = 0; i < this->objects.size(); ++i) {
        if (this->objects[i].getName() == objName) {
            deletedObj = this->objects[i];
            this->objects.erase(this->objects.begin() + i);
        }
    }

    return deletedObj;
}

bool AdvRoom::containsObject(string objName)
{
    // Returns true if object with objName is in the room.
    bool success = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->objects.size(); ++i) {
        if (this->objects[i].getName() == objName) {
            success = true;
        }
    }
    return success;
}

int AdvRoom::objectCount()
{
    return this->objects.size();
}

AdvObject AdvRoom::getObject(int index)
{
    return this->objects.at(index);
}

bool AdvRoom::hasBeenVisited()
{
    bool truth = this->isVisited;
    return truth;
}

void AdvRoom::setVisited(bool flag)
{
    this->isVisited = flag;
}

vector<AdvMotionTableEntry> AdvRoom::getMotionTable()
{
    vector<AdvMotionTableEntry> copyMotionTable = this->motionTable;
    return copyMotionTable;
}


int AdvRoom::getRoomNumber()
{
    int copyNumber = this->number;
    return copyNumber;
}
```

Comment: "problematic line is also shown" -- the so-called "problematic line" is not clearly highlighted, but it doesn't matter. Just because a program crashed on a particular line doesn't mean that's where the bug is. C++ doesn't work this way. The bug can be anywhere in the program, which is why stackoverflow.com's [help] tells you the only way to analyze the bug is to prepare a [mcve], otherwise it is unlikely anyone will be able to determine what it is. And it "seems to work fine in another computer" because a bug does not guarantee a crash 100% of the time.

Comment: Also, where is your `main` function?  Posting only a class is not enough.  You need to show a program that uses this class that duplicates the error.